# How to set a toggle keybinding in Awesome's rc.lua

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, awesome, lua

I'm running AwesomeWM on top of Ubuntu 20.04. I'd like to set a shortcut to disable the trackpad. My computer comes with built-in functionality to do that, but I'd like to change it from what it currently is.

The current keybinding is set to F10. I've determined via `xmodmap` that the keycode is 76, and that the functionality of the button (based on my understanding of `xmodmap`) is `XF86Switch_VT_10` (or, more specifically, `F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10`, even though that seems insane and I don't know why it's like that).

I've [discovered](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/disable-the-touchpad-on-linux/) that the way to toggle the trackpad from the command line is via `xinput set-prop <xinput number> "Device Enabled" 0`. So I know that I need to create some fuction in the `rc.lua` that looks something along the lines of `awful.key({}, "<something, maybe XF86Switch_VT_10>", function() awful.util.spawn("<line of code, maybe xinput set-prop # "Device Enabled" 0>") end`. I just don't know precisely what to put there.

Can someone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Find in your `rc.lua` file the `globalkeys = gears.table.join(` part
and add

```
  awful.key(
    {},
    'XF86Switch_VT_10',
    function()
      awful.spawn('xinput set-prop <xinput number> "Device Enabled" 0')
    end,
    {description = 'disable trackpad', group = 'hotkeys'}
  ),
```